# How to list folders using bash commands?

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

Is there any way to list just the folders in a directory using bash commands? ( as the `ls` command lists all the files and folders )

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use:

```
ls -d -- */
```

Since all directories end in `/`, this lists only the directories in the current path. The *-d* option ensures that only the directory names are printed, not their contents.

Comment: ls  -- */ 
           lists all directories with their contents below

Comment: @8088 What is the difference between `ls -d -- */` and `ls -d */`?

Comment: @Louis, `--` is conventionally used to mark the end of options, so that if a file is named `-l` ls won't interpret it as the long listing format option.

Answer (score 32):

Stephen Martin's response gave a warning, and listed the current folder as well, so I'd suggest

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

(This is on Linux; I could not find -maxdepth and -mindepth in the POSIX man page for find)

Comment: Older question I know. While I would too initially turn to find for this task, I like the `ls -d -- */` option, as `find` will find hidden directorties too. Which can sometimes be useful, but also sometimes cause trouble. I hope this comment might help others.  +1

Answer (score 13):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

Will list just folders. And as Teddy pointed out you'll need -maxdepth to stop it recusrsing into sub dirs

Comment: You probably want `-maxdepth 1` too.

Answer (score 7):

[Daniel’s answer is correct.](https://superuser.com/a/335397/3218) Here are some useful additions, though.

To avoid listing hidden folders (like `.git`), try this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d  \( ! -iname ".*" \)
```

And to replace [the dreaded dot slash](http://yergler.net/blog/2004/07/27/the-importance-of-dot-slash/) at the beginning of `find` output in some environments, use this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d  \( ! -iname ".*" \) | sed 's|^\./||g'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're "not supposed to" parse the output of ls, or so is said. The reasoning behind is that the output is intended to be human-readable and that can make it unnecessarily complicated to parse, if I recall.

if you don't want ls or find, you may want to try filtering "*" with "[ -d ]".

I did just that, for some reason ls and find weren't working (file names with spaces and brackets I guess, or somthing else I was overlooking), then I did something along the lines of

```
for f in * ; do [ -d "$f" ] && echo $f is indeed a folder ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to emphasize a thing that confused me out here, in respect to glob patterns selection; say you have this:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir testglob
$ for ix in {00,01,02,03} ; do mkdir testglob/mydir_${ix} ; done
$ for ix in {00,01,02,03} ; do touch testglob/myfile_${ix} ; done
$ for ix in {00,01,02,03} ; do touch testglob/mydir_${ix}.txt ; done
$ for ix in {00,01,02,03} ; do mkdir testglob/otherdir_${ix} ; done
$ tree testglob/
testglob/
├── mydir_00
├── mydir_00.txt
├── mydir_01
├── mydir_01.txt
├── mydir_02
├── mydir_02.txt
├── mydir_03
├── mydir_03.txt
├── myfile_00
├── myfile_01
├── myfile_02
├── myfile_03
├── otherdir_00
├── otherdir_01
├── otherdir_02
└── otherdir_03

8 directories, 8 files
```

So, say here you want to select only `mydir*` directories. Note that if you leave out the terminating slash, `ls -d` will list files as well:

```
$ ls -d testglob/mydir*   # also `ls -d -- testglob/mydir*`
testglob/mydir_00      testglob/mydir_01      testglob/mydir_02      testglob/mydir_03
testglob/mydir_00.txt  testglob/mydir_01.txt  testglob/mydir_02.txt  testglob/mydir_03.txt
```

... however, with a terminating slash, then only directories are listed:

```
$ ls -d testglob/mydir*/   # also `ls -d -- testglob/mydir*/`
testglob/mydir_00/  testglob/mydir_01/  testglob/mydir_02/  testglob/mydir_03/
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf "%s\n" */` will list all directories in the $PWD.

`echo */` will also work, but in a long one-line, more difficult when names have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
du
```

Or:

```
git ls-tree -d -r --name-only @
```

- http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html