# The command 'ls -d' is not displaying directories. Is there a way to get 'ls' to only display directories instead of files and directories?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

Is there a way to get `ls` to only display directories instead of files and directories?

From the man page:

```
   -d, --directory
          list directory entries instead of contents, and do not  derefer‐
          ence symbolic links
```

So if I type it at the `/` directory I expect to see only directories. Instead it shows "."

```
$ cd /
$ ls -d
.
```

I was expecting `ls -d` to show me this:

```
$ ls -d
bin    data  home        opt    sbin  sys      var
boot   dev   lib         media  proc  selinux  tmp
cdrom  etc   lost+found  mnt    root  srv      usr
```

Is there a way to get `ls` to only display directories instead of files and directories?

Comment: lsd *can* be very confusing.

Comment: @jin ls -d */ works. But why do I have to "*/" to get the out put I want.

Comment: @nelaar `-d` doesn't mean to list directories only, it means to not list directory contents. Try typing `ls */` and you'll see the contents of all the directories.

Comment: I have `ldir` alised to `ls -d */` in my `.bashrc` to make this easier...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list folders using bash commands?](http://superuser.com/questions/335376/how-to-list-folders-using-bash-commands)

Comment: ls can give you tons of information but not one single flag for just showing directories...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your expectations are based upon DOS Think/Windows Think and are wrong.  On MS-DOS, Windows, and indeed a few other IBM/Microsoft operating systems, wildcard expansion is done by the command itself, and things like the `/a` option to the `dir` command act as attribute filters during wildcard expansion.  `dir` expands wildcards like `*`, which the command interpreter passes to it as-is, and if `/a` is specified it applies the appropriate filters to what is returned.  (On some operating systems, the attribute filters can be given to the system call for enumerating a directory and the operating system kernel, or its filesystem drivers, applies them itself.)

On Unices and on Linux, wildcard expansion is done by the shell, and is oblivious to permissions.  When, in the root directory, you do

```
ls *
```

what the `ls` command itself *receives* from the shell is (something like)

```
ls bin home opt var boot dev tmp etc lost+found root usr
```

What the `-d`/`--directory` option does is *turn off what normally happens next*.  What normally happens next is that `ls` looks at each of its arguments in turn, sees that they are directories, and decides to enumerate their contents.  For arguments that name files, it just prints out the information for the file itself.  With the `-d` option, directories are treated just like files.  So `ls` prints out the information for each of the directories that is passed as its arguments, just as it would do if they were files.

So `-d` **is not** a "print only directories" option.  In fact, not only is there no such option; there *cannot be* such an option.  Wildcard expansion is done by the shell, and (in a POSIX `sh` at least) there's no way to tell the shell to check permission and file type bits when it expands `*` into a list of names.  To obtain a list of the names of directories alone, it is necessary either to use the `find` command, as explained by `ztank1013`, or to use the trick that a pathname ending with a slash implies the directory entry `.`, as explained by `Jin`.  (`Jin`'s trick ends up with the `ls` command receiving the arguments

```
ls bin/ home/ opt/ var/ boot/ dev/ tmp/ etc/ lost+found/ root/ usr/
```

because the pattern `*/` is in fact matching pathnames with two components, the second being empty, and so isn't *quite* doing what was desired.  In particular, it will treat symbolic links pointing to directories as if they were directories.)

The behaviour of `ls -d` without a `*` is a simple extension of the above.  One simply has to know one more thing about `ls`: When it is given no arguments, it assumes a default argument of `.`.  Now *without* the `-d` option, the aforementioned behaviour leads to the contents of the directory named by `.` being enumerated and the information for its contents displayed.  *With* the `-d` option, the directory `.` is treated just as if it were a file, and its own information is displayed, rather than its contents enumerated.

Comment: thanks you. I realize I was not thinking about wildcard expansion correctly. You have clarified that very well for me. You have helped a lot. I can actually say I get it.

Comment: "there _cannot_ be such an option" - that's a rather strong statement - the implementation of such an option is obvious: see a non-directory argument and ignore it. What _can't_ be implemented is the equivalent of `dir /s *.txt` [without resorting to quoting wildcards as for find]

Comment: It's a strong and true statement for a system like Unix where wildcard expansion is divorced from entry type checking.  Your hypothetical implementation is erroneous.  What you describe _still expands `*` to include the non-directories_, with all of the filesystem race conditions and subtle scripting connotations that that entails.  Whereas `dir /a:d` will, on operating systems that have this functionality in the system API, skip non-directories immediately without even returning them to application-mode code.

Comment: Right, but there's no logical reason ls _can't_ have an option which will filter out items that were passed in as arguments. The fact that "wildcard expansion is divorced from entry type checking" is irrelevant, since this has nothing _at all_ to do with wildcard expansion - only entry type checking, which there is no reason it cannot be done _entirely_ within ls. If ls --color can shade them blue, ls -F can put a / after them, and ls -l can put a 'd' in the mode, then some other hypothetical option could omit them. That such an option does not exist doesn't mean it "_cannot_".

Comment: Kiddo, it's not only relevant; it's the core of the problem.  If you don't understand that, you don't understand one of the fundamentals of Unix.  Think!  Start by re-reading what I wrote and _think_ about what race conditions and subtle scripting connotations I referred to.  The race conditions are fairly well known, and the scripting connotations can be seen with a little applied thought.

Comment: Random832 makes a decent point: `ls` *could* have an option to filter files or directories, and this isn't mutually exclusive with having the shell do expansion. There's no race condition within ls: it can filter it as it stats the files normally. (There is already a race between the shell expansion and ls, FWIW.) I think shell expansion is only part of the reason: shell expansion (and filtering in general) is not implemented in ls because it would need to be implemented again in cp, mv, etc. Unix is a "do one thing and do it well". If you need advanced filtering, there are tools for that.

Comment: The `ls -p` option adds a `/` symbol to directories only. There is no reason not to extend the output printing capabilities with something that does only output these (rather than `ls -p | grep /`).

Comment: You and Thanatos, even though I've explained it twice already, have entirely missed the point. It's not about `ls` being altered to treat directories differently, as if somehow it didn't already. _We know that it can and it does. That is right there in the answer._ You've both not thought about what I said to think about, including the fundamentals of Unix, which mean that there's no way for an option to `ls` to control shell wildcard expansion. Random832 was specifically contradicting _that_ statement of mine, and providing as supposed proof a mechanism that doesn't actually work as claimed.

Comment: @JdeBP, ad-hominem attacks ("kiddo") and arrogance (everybody except you does not know "the fundamentals of Unix") do not belong to a technical discussion. Furthermore, you're pulling a straw man when you argue that a command option cannot control wildcard expansion done by shell. _Of course, it cannot!_ Neither Random832, nor Thanatos, nor Anne van Rossum, and not even the question itself mention wildcards in any way. The objection was that `ls --only-directories .` option could be added to `ls` eventually.

Comment: Answer is pedantic and presumptuous. Consider *ls -l* which lists all the stuff in the working directory. One might very reasonably expect *ls -d* to just list all the *directories* in the current directory (especially given the output of *man ls*, which OP quoted). The convention of showing everything in the working directory, subject to some constraint set by an option flag, is ubiquitous in bash.  There is nothing weird or MSDOSish about it at all. Whatever happened to just answering the question.

Comment: Ls could just add the "directories only" flag. 
With this hack "ls -d */" you have to be in the directory to see subdirectories.

Comment: Myy expectations have nothing to do with Windows. Have a downvote. I didn't read the rest.

Answer (score 30):

You can use`ls -d */`, or `ls -d .*/` for hidden directories.

Comment: clever trick using the / !

Comment: Yeah this is good. Is there any case where this doesn't work?

Comment: +1 for providing the answer in one line. I'm guessing the accepted answer also has it, somewhere.

Comment: How can you use this in a script without being in the directory already?

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
 find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

to get just directories under your current location.

Answer (score 5):

You might also like

```
tree -d
```

which neatly lists all directories and subdirectories with a graphical depiction of the tree structure.

Comment: And for only one level deep: `tree -dL 1`

Comment: Unfortunately you can't combine much with tree.
# tree -d | grep wc -l 
(standard input)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see directories only with detail like `ls -l` (ELL) option then you can use below:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -ls;
```

Above will only give you the detail like you get with the `-l` option.

Comment: It may be even better to use `find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ls -d {} +` to get output in the usual `ls`format.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the job done in another way, try this:

`ls -l | grep ^d`

Although a single tool is enough in this situation. Pipe line is always there to help you. I like the flexibility in Linux, which I wish you do.

Comment: This is going to filter out more than directories.

Comment: @Slomojo, this will filter out everything but directories. What did you mean?

Comment: Yeah, you need the -l (long) so that permissions head up the line. "d" for directory. Plus you get a "long" listing of a directory entry which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will rectify your need. The below command will list only directories in a given path.

```
ls -F <path> | grep /
```

Example:

```
ls -F ~ | grep /
```