# chmod throws missing operand on 764, OK on 664

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, permissions, chmod

Having set everything in my project to `777` (`rwxrwxrwx`) for debugging purposes, I wanted to dial down the openness and set the directories (not the files) in the root folder to `664` (`rw-rw-r--`).

To do this I used (from [How to list folders using bash commands?](https://superuser.com/questions/335376/how-to-list-folders-using-bash-commands)):

```
chmod 664 -- */
```

This worked as expected. Then I realized I needed the execution bit on directories to enter them. So I tried:

```
chmod 764 -- */
```

But that threw a `missing operand after "764"` error.

I can change the permissions by hand (`chmod 764 <dir-name>`) and there aren't that many directories so it's not a big problem, but I'd like to understand.

**Why can't I use `chmod 764 */` to set the directories in my current path to `rwxrw-r--`?**

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may like to know that `chmod +X` (possibly together with `--recursive`) would be appropriate for this situation; it grants execute/search permission only if a file is a directory or already had execute permission (from `info '(coreutils.info.gz)Conditional Executability'`).

Answer (score 1):

This would make sense if you have set shell glob options so that

- `*` includes names beginning with `.`, and
- a wildcard that doesn’t match anything just disappears, rather than persisting as itself. 
  (E.g., if you don’t have any files whose names begin with `foo`,
  the command `echo foo*` prints a blank line rather than printing `foo*` literally.)

If the above are true, then the first command set `.` to mode 664,
which means that you didn’t have permission to read `.` when you issued the second command. 
So the `*/` couldn’t be expanded, and `chmod 764 -- */` became `chmod 764 --`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However after checking, `ls -la` shows `./` to `774`, and doing `sudo chmod 764 -- */` still throws the missing operand error...