# Previous and next folder using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, date, directory-listing

This is similar to [How to list folders using bash commands?](https://superuser.com/questions/335376/how-to-list-folders-using-bash-commands).  I have a folder structure of the format foo/YYYY/MM/DD/HHMM (at 10 minute intervals).  What is the easiest way to get the previous and next folder's name?

I thought of

```
sTimeNow=$(date "${iYear}/${iMnt}/${iDay} ${iHr}:${iMin):00")
sTimeBefore=$(date "${sTimeNow} - "10 minutes")
sTimeAfter=$(date "${sTimeNow} + "10 minutes")
```

and with a bit (understament...) of formatting could get the two directories.
However the date maths probably not the best way to go about it, and I have missing dates (which is my ultimate aim to fix)

Also thought of populating a list

```
MyList='ls -dr *"
iFolder= get current folder index (how?)
sFolderBefore=$Mylist[${iFolder}-1]  so much easier
sFolderAfter=$Mylist[${iFolder}+1]
```

(all the above likely to have syntax errors, apologies novice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like:

```
find {root_of_folders} -type d | sort | grep -A 1 "$(basename "$PWD")\$" | tail -1
```

In other words: lits all the dirs and find the one that comes after the current one in the list. With the ending `\$` it iterates your subdirectories, without it it goes to the next directory at same level.

For the previous directory you use `-B 1` and `head -1`.

Edit: some enhancements:

1. the code above has problems if file names contain things that can be interpreted as regexp syntax (characters in brackets, in particular), so better make this a `grep -F` (but you can no longer use the `\$`)
2. To avoid false hits if a directory name is a non-initial part of another one, prefix with a / to force the match to occur from the beginning.

So, the improved form is:

```
find {root_of_folders} -type d | sort | grep -A 1 -F "/$(basename "$PWD")" | tail -1
```

Comment: Nice, I replaced {root_of_folders) with .. and it works perfectly.
Not sure I follow the \$ it gives me the same answer with and without it

Comment: Also it only works for that day. e.g. from foo/2017/03/02/0000 it says the previous is foo/2017/03/02/0000.  Works perfectly if it's the same day.

Comment: There is a difference if there are subdirectories. But since you are using `..` you must have only one level.

Comment: That's because you are using `..` and not `/path/to/foo`.